# can timer interrupt be masked?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, scheduler, interrupt-handling

I am interested to know if timer interrupts can be masked.. ? Consider a case of ppc, run_local_timers() function in "kernel/timer.c" is called by the local, per-CPU timer interrupt.

So is there any possibility that this timer interrupt is masked and run_local_timers() function is not called during that time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All interrupts, except NMI, can be masked. This includes the timer interrupt.
In general, while hardware interrupts are being processed, interrupts are disabled.

Note that masking interrupts for more than a very short while affects the system badly.